# SQL Stored Procedure Parsing

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

For the past 6 months I've been trying to write a procedure which dynamically maps out the execution path of business logic.

Previously I've gone down the route of looking at the sys.sql_dependencies tables to map out the execution flow however within the Procedures we have conditional logic which determines if some procedures get called or not.

My main mechanism for doing this so far is to output the specification of an procedure into a temporary table and output any EXEC or IF logic within that

```
DECLARE @TRAVERSAL_DEFINITION TABLE
(
ROW_ID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
SP_TEXT VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @TRAVERSAL_DEFINITION
(SP_TEXT)
exec sp_helptext '[SCHEMA].[PROCEDURE]'

SELECT TD_1.ROW_ID, 
       LTRIM(TD_1.SP_TEXT), 
       CASE WHEN LTRIM(SP_TEXT) LIKE 'IF%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
       CASE WHEN LTRIM(SP_TEXT) LIKE 'EXEC%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
       IF_START.ROW_ID,
       IF_END.ROW_ID
 FROM @TRAVERSAL_DEFINITION TD_1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(ROW_ID) AS ROW_ID 
               FROM @TRAVERSAL_DEFINITION TD_2 WHERE LTRIM(SP_TEXT) LIKE 'END%'              
                AND TD_2.ROW_ID > TD_1.ROW_ID) IF_END
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(ROW_ID) AS ROW_ID 
              FROM @TRAVERSAL_DEFINITION TD_2 
             WHERE LTRIM(SP_TEXT) LIKE 'BEGIN%' 
               AND TD_2.ROW_ID > TD_1.ROW_ID) IF_START
WHERE (LTRIM(SP_TEXT) LIKE 'IF%' OR LTRIM(SP_TEXT) LIKE 'EXEC%')
ORDER BY TD_1.ROW_ID
```

Has anyone come across this particular problem before and if so what approach/solution have you taken?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In case you choose to use ScriptDom to parse the sprocs for dependencies, you may find a simple GUI tool I created useful: https://github.com/wangzq/TsqlScriptDom The tool is written in F# itself but once you have the knowledge of which object to look for you should be able to easily use that in your own parsing code.

Answer (score 0):

Great question - I hope you can use C# (or any .net language)

If you create an SSDT project and import your schema you can use the DacFx project which does exactly what you want - gives you references from one object to the next.

There are two main parts for you to look at, the first is the DacFx api that loads dacpacs and gives you a TSqlModel you can query for relationships.

The second part is the ScriptDom which will let you parse some SQL and retrieve things like the keywords and statements.

For a sample see:

https://github.com/GoEddie/DacpacExplorer

If you are particularly interested in references there is a new API https://github.com/Microsoft/DACExtensions which is much simpler to use than the existing one so I would suggest you use that.

ed

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have permissions to create a DacPac of our Dev databases - due to restrictions put on by our DBA team.

Comment: If life were only that easy ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry for being facetious - Do you know what their specific objection is?

Comment: From the way our permissions are structured developers are not allowed DBO access on our development systems and there are some auditing tables which are only accessible by their team. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: ok, personallly I would do everything I could to get out of that situation, this might help https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/the-unnecessary-evil-of-the-shared-development-database/ try to get your own instance of the database and use SSDT - there is no point writing your own parsing system when there is already an excellent one that is totally free.